# Why can't I pipe output from `nvim -c 'q' --startuptime >(tail -n 1) `

Tags: shell, for-loop, awk, pipe, neovim

I am trying to profile the startup time of a terminal application.

This involves opening and closing the app several times using a `for` loop, grabbing the relevant lines of output, and then piping them to `awk` to calculate the average startup time.

The simplest form of my command that fails is this: `nvim -c 'q' --startuptime >(tail -n 1) | awk '{ print $1 }'`.

It not only fails to run properly, it messes with my shell (zsh) ui in that the cursor disappears, and I need to open a new terminal window to fix the problem.

If I don't include the pipe, the command successfully outputs to my terminal, and if I then manually copy the output from my terminal to the clipboard, use my window manager's 'paste from clipboard' command, and pipe it to `awk`, the output is as expected.

But if instead of piping to `awk` I pipe to my clipboard, I still see the output in my terminal, and if I then paste my clipboard's contents into a new file, I get this kind of gibberish:

```
嬛ㄿ㐰根嬛㈲〻〻᭴㽛栱㴛嬛ᭈ䩛崛ㄱ㼻ᬇ㽛〲㐰᭨㍛栴嬛㈿栵嬛㈿氵嬛཭嬛ᭈ䩛嬛ㄿ〰栴嬛′᭱㉛焠嬛㌲ᭂ㍛栴嬛㈿栵嬛㈿氵嬛′᭱浛ᬏ㍛栴嬛㈿栵嬛ㄿ᭬ᬾ㽛〱㤴᭬㉛㬳㬰琰嬛㈿〰水嬛ㄿ〰水嬛㐳᭨㽛㔲h
```

I suspect that opening and closing a terminal application as part of the command is what's causing the problem, but can anyone help me understand more precisely what's going wrong (and ideally how to fix it)?

Full command I'm working on:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10)
  do nvim -c 'q' --startuptime >(tail -n1 | sed 's/^0*//')
done | awk NF | awk '
  BEGIN{ min = 1000; sum = 0 } 
  $1 > max { max = $1 } 
  $1 < min { min = $1 } 
  { sum = sum + $1 } 
  END { print "Mean: ", sum / NR, "Max: " max, "Min: ", min, "Range: ", max - min }'
```

Comment: `nvim` probably outputs screen controlling escape sequences. Run it in a separate window. Like I think `xfce4-terminal --execute nvim` or `screen -d -m nvim`

Comment: ...if you want to capture those sequences in a way that'll work even if it's trying to write them to the `/dev/tty`, then `unbuffer` is your friend. In any event, `less` should show them; pipe to that, or `hexdump`, or similar.

Comment: Actually, given the use case, I'd just stop using `--startuptime` altogether in favor of `time { nvi -c q &>/dev/null; }`